# Temporarily lost phone, what to do about Signal backups?

Tags: backup, lost-phone, signal-private-messenger

I've lost access to my phone, with a Signal installation with a lot of old messages I'd rather not lose. I know that most likely I'll get the phone back within 6 months though.

I would also like to be able to access my old group chats and number in the meantime, on my new temporary phone.

I've understood that if i transfer my number and account to my new phone, my lost phone shouldn't lose its messages, it should just "stop all messaging and calling on your old phone" https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007062452-What-do-I-do-if-my-phone-is-lost-or-stolen-

But when I get the lost phone back, will I be able to reactivate that installation and not lose the history? If not, would I at least be able to create a backup from it, to be able to reinstall and recover the backup? The documentation doesn't clarify exactly what a "deactivated" account is able to do.

When going back to my old phone, I'd be fine with losing the short history on my temporary phone.

Comment: I think this is off-topic here as Android has nothing to do with this.  What will happen is determined totally by the developers at Signal.

Answer (score 0):

## Careful: There is a difference between linking another phone to your Signal account and transferring your account to a new phone.

### Linking another phone:

If you just link another replacement device, you can go back to your original device and re-link it without the data on your old device being lost. The data of the replacement device will **not** be synced to the original device. This works only if you have NOT uninstalled the app on your original device.
[According to Exallium (Signal Developer)](https://ww.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/13phum3/i_need_to_send_my_phone_in_for_repair_can_i/jl9wi5l/)

### Transferring to another phone

Transferring consists of the following steps on Android:
On the new phone, install Signal > select Transfer or restore account > enable permissions > select Transfer from Android device > Continue. If you have transferred to a new device you **won't** be able to access the data upon reclaiming your original phone!

> Currently, we only support phones as primary devices, which means only one can be registered (this has to do with key generation and a bunch of other crypto stuff that is beyond my knowledge).

> When a device becomes unregistered (because it was offline for a long time, or because the number was registered somewhere else) we don't delete the data. I'm pretty sure I hit this scenario at least weekly via testing. **If you do a device transfer, then we do clear data on the old device after the transfer is completed.**

### Do a backup on original device if version allows

Also note that Signal v 5.44.3 as well as v 6.19.9 **allow** you to backup, even **after** the device is no longer registered

Version 6.20.6 does **not** allow you to backup after unlinking, as the options to make a new backup are greyed out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but all these suggestions assume I still have access to my old phone, which I don't.

Comment: But that reddit thread you linked to is very interesting, thanks!

Comment: sorry, I thought you had only temporarily lost it and knew you were going to get it back. Good luck though

Comment: I will get it back, but by then I don't need advice anymore, then I'll just use that phone.